# Mono Gtk Documentation?

Tags: c#, documentation, mono, gtk

Does anyone know of any good documentation for Gtk# for Mono?  I added a key release handler and can't for the life of me figure out how to determine which key was actually pressed.  I'm starting to understand why everyone avoids developing multiplatform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have everything explained here:

http://www.mono-project.com/Monodoc

You can even download a tool in order to browse the documentation on your computer.
The place where you want to go is the monodoc directly, section Gnome Libraries >> Gtk:

http://docs.go-mono.com/

About your problem with the key handler, it sould look like this one:

```
    protected virtual void OnTableKeyPress(object o, Gtk.KeyPressEventArgs args)
    {
        if ( args.Event.Key == Gdk.Key.Alt_L ) {
             Util.MsgInfo( "Left alt pressed!" );
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks.  Although it ended up being that MonoDevelop couldn't tell the difference between Gdk.Key and Gtk.Key implicitly, leading me to believe that Key was a useless class instead of the useful enum I needed.